# Scope_Identity linking 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables -

```
create table Category    
(
    CategoryId int identity (1,1) not null,     
    Name varchar (40) not null,

    constraint PK_Category  primary key (CategoryId) 
)
GO

create table Product
(
    ProductId int identity (1,1) not null,
    CategoryId int not null,
    Name varchar(40) not null,    

    constraint PK_Product primary key (ProductId),
    constraint FK_Product_Category foreign key (CategoryId) references Category (CategoryId)
)
GO
```

What I am trying to do in SQL is whenever a `CategoryId` is entered in the `Category` table it will appear in the `CategoryId` of the `Product` table, as you can see it is the foreign key in `Product` table.

I have read about `scope_identity` and triggers however I'm not sure where to begin.

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved...) You know, these two products have very different triggers...

Comment: sorry about that, its SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption of whenever you add a category, its CategoryID should appear in Products CategoryID column is wrong.

It will only appear in CategoryID column of Products table when you actually add a Product with that category.

You can create a stored procedure to add products and categories for you, which checks if there is a category and grabs a categoryId for that category and if a category doesnt exit it adds for you.

Something like ....

### PROCEDURE DEFINITION

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_Product 
 @CategoryName  VarChar(40)
,@ProductName   VarChar(40)
,@ProductID     Int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @CategoryID INT;

SELECT @CategoryID = CategoryId FROM Category WHERE Name = @CategoryName

    IF (@CategoryID IS NULL)
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO Category(Name)
       VALUES (@CategoryName)

       SET @CategoryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Product
          WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryId AND Name = @ProductName)
   BEGIN
      RAISERROR('Product already exists' ,16,1)
      SET @ProductID = 0;
      RETURN;
   END
ELSE 
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Product (CategoryId , Name)
    VALUES (@CategoryID , @ProductName)
      SET @ProductID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
  END
END
```

### PROCEDURE EXECUTION

```
DECLARE @ProductID INT;
EXEC Insert_Product @CategoryName = 'Dairy'
                   ,@CategoryName = 'Milk'
                   ,@ProductID    = @ProductID OUTPUT
```